# Edit compiled css file

Tags: css

I am using a theme created by someone else and I want to add code to the css file.
But the file is compiled. Is there a way to edit the css file correctly?

The file is located at: https://www.metalura.bvdodev.nl/wp-content/themes/metalurav2/css/main-e3a6e235.css

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can use unminifier following is the link.

[Unminifier](https://mrcoles.com/blog/css-unminify/)

Answer (score 0):

Use some code 'beautifier' so that you can read the code as a Human.

[Prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier) is a good option

Answer (score 0):

You can **unminify** with [unminify.com](https://unminify.com) and use a **code beautifier**, like [freeformatter.com](https://www.freeformatter.com/css-beautifier.html).

Anyways, [click here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RLckqh2eM-EUm46ACRy4LoYzTweZoKvP) to get your new file (ready to code).

And [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) you can learn more about Minification.